# Accessing Windows 8 User Identity

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, identity

I'm writing a simple little game and I am planning on implementing a leaderboard for it.  To get a entry in the leaderboard, I need a name for the user.

Is it best practice to ask for a name the first time they play, or could I access the users Identity somehow, so I do not have to implement the UI to get the users .. say "First Name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to get the name. So you need to ask the user he opens the app first time .

But I like the solution, to put a predefined name in (like "Player" or maybe better "Player{RandomNumber}") and let the user change this. But it's possible to get the Live Id (anonymous) to identify the user in the background and update his last entry for example. See [Using Windows Live ID authentication in a Windows Phone 8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017648/using-windows-live-id-authentication-in-a-windows-phone-8-app)