# API to get the friendly name of your Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: windows-phone-8, device-name

Is there a way to get the name of your phone?  The name you see in Windows Explorer properties as the device name?

I have looked at **Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName** but that appears to be different.
I have looked at **DeviceExtendedProperties** but that is mostly deprecated now.

The phone prompts you for this name during setup.  I can also see this name and change it in the WinRT App for WP8 preferences.  But I'm not seeing a way to get it by API.

(I would like this name so that I can pass it on to a web service that shows a device list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no public WP8 API to retrieve the user friendly Device Name. If you're looking to uniquely identify the phone's use [ANID2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972829/im-not-able-to-get-my-anid).

Comment: Thanks, I have been using the DeviceUniqueId for a key, I just wanted display name. Understandable if its locked down.  Guess I can always prompt for one.

Comment: Isn't Alexander's or Richard's answer correct technically? It works fine for me.

Answer (score 9):

Windows.Networking.Proximity.PeerFinder.DisplayName will give you the name the user has given to the phone

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the base API has anything that will allow you to do that, probably due to security concerns!

Comment: Just curious, but why do you say it's a security concern? Note: I've never owned nor interacted with a WP8 device in this manner

Comment: I did turn on ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE but the DeviceName I'm seeing looks auto-generated ... RM-824_nam_att_101 for my Nokia.

Comment: Just think of the people that name their device with their own first & last name!... Anything that can be used to uniquely identify a device and associate with a specific user IS a security concern, so that's why I think there is no away on getting the device name with the current SDK!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the manufacturer and model name. For my Nokia Lumia 930, this logs "NOKIA RM-1045_1044" it's not the friendliest name but it'll let you differentiate between devices.

```
var deviceInformation = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();
console.log(deviceInformation.systemSku);
```